# How to solve globalFilter is not property of p-table

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

When I run the application I face error as

> Can't bind to 'globalFilter' since it isn't a known property of 'p-table'.
>       1. If 'p-table' is an Angular component and it has 'globalFilter' input, then verify that it is part of this module.

HTML:

```
<p-table [columns]="tableHeaders" [value]="listEmrAllergy" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" (onLazyLoad)="loadLazy($event)" [totalRecords]="totalcount" [lazy]="!press" [globalFilter]="dt">
```

TS:

```
import { TableModule } from 'primeng/table';
```

Comment: Is it part of the module ?

Comment: ya it is part of module

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to add filter inside lazy p-table do something like this.

```
     <p-table [columns]="tableHeaders" [value]="listEmrAllergy" [paginator]="true"
         [rows]="10" (onLazyLoad)="loadLazy($event)" [totalRecords]="totalcount" [lazy]="!press" 
[globalFilterFields]="tableHeaders" #tt>
                 <input type="text" pInputText placeholder="Global Filter" (input)="tt.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')" >
     </p-table>
```

For [globalFilterFields] property, you need to pass columns name.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This works and saved my day

Comment: How did you solve  -> $event.target.value  TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

Comment: I did exact same thing but the global filter not working with the lazyload.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple to fix this issue. Unfortunately PrimeNg doesn't have good documentation.
You need to do three things:

1. In your `<input>` element, add the following:

   `<input type="text" pInputText placeholder="Enter Filter Text" id="filterText" 
                   (input)="tt.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'equals')" style="width:auto">` The `(input)` part is the important one where `"tt"` is the identifier of your `p-treeTable` as written in point 2.
2. `<p-treeTable #tt [value]="testData" [scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="400px" scrollWidth="300px" [globalFilterFields]="['label','dataId']">
                       <ng-template pTemplate="caption">`
3. You need to define the `[globalFilterFields]` property inside `p-treeTable` which takes as input an array of columns on which you want to perform your search.

Answer (score 0):

Have a better look at the [doc](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/filter) and you will see that there is no *globalFilter* property.

You should replace your code with something like that :

```
<p-table #dt [columns]="tableHeaders" [value]="listEmrAllergy" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" (onLazyLoad)="loadLazy($event)"
 [totalRecords]="totalcount" [lazy]="!press">
    <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
        <div style="text-align: right">
            <i class="fa fa-search" style="margin:4px 4px 0 0"></i>
            <input type="text" pInputText size="50" placeholder="Global Filter" (input)="dt.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')"
             style="width:auto">
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

I removed `[globalFilter]="dt"` and added `#dt`. I also added a caption template with an input for the global filter you want.

Comment: and globalFilterFields array null An array of fields as string to use in global filtering. "globalFilterFields" is there in the documentation section. Any idea how to tackle with lazy load

Comment: globalFilter != globalFilterFields : globalFilter exists only for deprecated `p-datatable`. For filtering with lazy loading, see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49236929/how-to-use-filter-in-primeng-turbotable-with-lazy-load) post.